# Building a dashboard in Next.js : best practices to make pages private with roles, without "flickering", using JWT authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, jwt

Considering that we have:

- A backend already ready (not in Next) with authentication using JWT pattern and a home-made RBAC
- 4 private pages only for unauthenticated people (login, signup, forgot password, reset password)
- ~25+ private pages for the dashboard
- 1 public page for dashboard presentation
- Hundreds of dashboard related components (+ thousands of design system components)

Users should:

- login before accessing the dashboard
- if unauthenticated and accessing private route, should be redirected to `/login` without flickering
- if authenticated and accessing routes for unauthenticated users, should be redirected to `/profile` without flickering)

My logic right now for dealing with JWT:

```js
// lib/axios.js

import Axios from 'axios';
import { getCookie, removeCookies } from 'cookies-next';
import qs from 'qs';

export const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  paramsSerializer: (params) =>
    qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' }),
  withCredentials: true,
});

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = getCookie('access_token');
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      config.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // we need to implement refresh pattern
      // const refresh = await refreshToken();
      removeCookies('access_token');
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// For SWR
export const fetcher = async (...args) => await axios.get(...args).data;
```

I've been accumulating researches about this and I found so many different answers. So far I found:

- Provider to put in `_app.js` with hard-coded private routes in an array
- Different HoC functions inside every page like `withPrivate` or `withPublic`
- Using `getServerSideProps` with redirection to login inside every page
- `nextAuth` but I'm not sure because it seems like it's building a backend and we've got one already
- `_middleware` that can do the redirection apparently
- It seems like it's possible to use `SWR`, `Suspense` and `Error Boundaries` but I'm not sure if it's adapted for this kind of cases...

Any clue about how I should do ?

Comment: I think the best way to avoid any flash of private content to unauthenticated users (which I suppose is what you want to achieve), redirecting via `getServerSideProps` would be the best option. Any client side verification could produce some of these "flashes".

Comment: @ivanatias Thanks for your answer, that's exactly what I want to achieve ! I thought about using `getServerSideProps` but since it's a dashboard, I don't need SEO so... I don't really need to render on server anything, and therefore slow down my app. It'd totally solve these "flashes" though, you're totally right !

Comment: Well, since you would be using `getServerSideProps` mostly for authentication purposes, it wouldn't matter for SEO anyway. Crawlers can't access routes that are restricted for logged in users (with server-side authentication).

Comment: You can check some examples of auth patterns in Nextjs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication)

Comment: I got your point, I already used Next's SSR (and ISR) before. But never for authenticated pages, only in SEO-related purpose pages.
First time I'm building a dashboard using Next. Don't you think it'd slow down the whole app if we go for SSR instead of CSR for every page ? I wonder if it's worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tests with different techniques, I decided to go for Next.js new middleware incredible feature.

If anybody struggles with this topic like I did, here is my code:

```js
// _middleware.js in /pages, works also with Typescript .ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { isAuthValid } from '@/lib/auth'

export function middleware(req) {
  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login') ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/signup') ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/forgot') ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/reset')
  ) {
    if (isAuthValid(req)) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/profile', req.url));
    }
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // All other routes
  if (isAuthValid(req)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
  return NextResponse.redirect(
    new URL(`/login?from=${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url)
  );
}
```

Be careful though as this file name and location will change in new Next.js `12.2` version, under the name of `middleware.js` (or `.ts`) in your root folder, whether it's root or `src` depending on your configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use static generation and never plan to `getServerSideProps` works.

If you plan to use Vercel to host, `_middleware` could be a good option too, however, 3rd party hosting support is lagging.

Since you already have your own auth, `nextAuth` doesn't seem to be a good choice.

I'd recommend using an Auth context - wrapping every page with an HOC is isn't necessary anymore.

You can prevent the flickering by using a loading screen or spinner.

---

Here is an example of an auth context.

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback, createContext } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const AuthContext = createContext(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { asPath, push } = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  // if you use trailing slash you'd need to add them to each route
  const isAuthRoute = ["/login", "/signup", "/forgot", "/reset"].includes(asPath);

  const redirectToLogin = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setUser(null);
      await push('/login');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Could not redirect to login");
    }
  }, [push]);

  const signOut = async () => {
    try {
      await authServiceSignout();
      await redirectToLogin();
    } catch {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  };

  const goHome = useCallback(() => push('/'), [push]);

  // check if user is logged in on every route changes and
  // redirect accordingly
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const user = await getUserOrJWT();
      if (user) {
        setUser(user); // user details
        if (isAuthRoute) await goHome();
      } else if (!isAuthRoute) {
        await redirectToLogin();
      }
    };
    getUser();
  }, [asPath, goHome, isAuthRoute, redirectToLogin]);

  if (!user && isAuthRoute) return <>{children}</>;
  if (!user) return <>Loading or loading spinner</>;

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signOut }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I deleted a bunch of code so it probably doesn't work direct copy and paste but you can get the idea.

`isAuthRoute` only needs to return true/false so another good options if your dashboard routes all start with `/dashboard` you can use `asPath.startsWith('/dashboard')` instead.

We conditionally rendered the auth context because it's not needed on public pages and it also clears the user context on logout so we don't need to worry about leaking old user data via context.

We also use local storage and the window's broadcast channel to listen for logout calls. This allows us to log the user out in every tab and window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sean !! It was helpful.
I think there is a "flash" when there is an authenticated user who tries to access a public page like "/login" for example. It displays the login content first

Comment: If you look at my example - content for a page a user can't access is never shown.

Comment: Yes, I implemented your example and it works well, the only case that doesn't is the one I mentionned above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for opening the discussion around this topic. My use-case is almost exactly like the OP's example. I'm also using SSR (primarily).

I have also gone through numerous pitfalls and challenges in getting it to work, but the build failed due to 'jsonwebtoken' lib having the eval error in middleware. From there I used the 'cookies-next' lib, but with Next.js v12.2.0 having integrated the cookies.get() (cookies: NextCookies) in the NextRequest, I managed to work with that rather.

I use:

- `cookie` lib to 'parse' and 'serialize', but might switch this out with Next.js internal functions soon.
- `jose` for 'SignJWT', 'jwtVerify' - latest version don't use Native Node.js API (good for middleware).

In my `_app` > `getInitialProps`:

```
// _app.tsx

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext: AppContext) => {
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
    let customerData = {};
    if (!!appContext.ctx.req) {
        /*
         * Expose the cookie to the page props of all the pages
         * for client-side auth datafetching
         */
        const cookie = parse(appContext.ctx.req.headers.cookie || '');
        appProps.pageProps[JWT_COOKIE_NAME] = cookie[JWT_COOKIE_NAME];
        /*
         * If the user is logged in, we'll verify the JWT and get the user data
         */
        const userJWT = await verifyAuthCookieOnReload(appContext.ctx);
        if (userJWT) {
            const { id, token } = userJWT;
            customerData = await UserService.getCustomer(id, token);
        }
    }

    const props = { ...appProps, customerData };

    return props;
};
```

I have a helper file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-server-import-in-page
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import type { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { parse, serialize } from 'cookie';
import { SignJWT, jwtVerify, JWTPayload } from 'jose';
import { JWT_SECRET, JWT_COOKIE_NAME } from '@constants/env';

export type UserJWTPayload = JWTPayload & JwtUserData & {
    jti: string;
    iat: number;
};

export type JwtUserData = {
    id: string;
    token: string;
};

export const setUserJWTCookie = async (userData: JwtUserData | {}, logoutTime?: number) => {
    const time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    let expireTime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14; // 14 days
    if (logoutTime) {
        expireTime = logoutTime; // override for logout "-1"
    }
    const token = await new SignJWT(userData)
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'HS256' })
        .setJti(nanoid())
        .setIssuedAt()
        .setExpirationTime(time + expireTime)
        .sign(new TextEncoder().encode(JWT_SECRET));

    return serialize(JWT_COOKIE_NAME, token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        sameSite: 'strict',
        maxAge: expireTime,
        path: '/'
    });
};

export const verifyAuthCookie = async (request: NextRequest): Promise<UserJWTPayload | undefined> => {
    const token = request.cookies.get(JWT_COOKIE_NAME);
    return await verify(token);
}

export const verifyAuthCookieOnReload = async (context: NextPageContext): Promise<UserJWTPayload | undefined> => {
    const cookie = parse(context?.req?.headers.cookie || '');
    const token = cookie[JWT_COOKIE_NAME];
    return await verify(token);
};

export const verify = async (token: string | undefined) => {
    if (!token) {
        return undefined;
    }
    try {
        const { payload } = await jwtVerify(token, new TextEncoder().encode(JWT_SECRET));
        return payload as UserJWTPayload;
    } catch (err) {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

My use-case is to "force" a user login, before being able to navigate the site. I'm just struggling to manage the logic in my middleware, even when using the examples given in this post. I think I'm still not handling the data flow correctly as it does not prevent any navigation or redirect as wanted.

I hope this example has some information to your current use-case and how to approach it :)